# how to pass request parameter in spring weflow

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

i am using using spring webflow. how can i pass id from viewstate  to action state as request parameter . not to sub flow or other flow . in the same same flow itself .
example:
and in the action state

```
<input type="submit" name="_eventID_submit&id=123">
    <view-state id="view" view="/jsp/a.jsp" >
    <transition on="submit" to="get"></transition>
    </view-state>

    <action-state id="get">
    <on entry>
    <set name="flowScope.id" value="requestParameters.id" />
    </onentry>
    <evaluate expression="a.view(id)"></evaluate>
    <transition on="success" to="view"></transition>
    </action-state>
```

Comment: Just like in any form, with a hidden field?

Comment: thank @JBNizet .is their is any other way.so using script i need to set id to the hidden field on selection